# Retrieve data from mysql and display in the form of ascii text table in browser

Tags: php, mysql, text, ascii

How to query mysql data and display it in the form of ascii text table in a Browser, just as you get it in command line.  A small example is given below :

```
+------+---------+---------------------+------------+
| S.No | S.R.NO. | EMPLOYEE NAME       | D.O.B      |
+------+---------+---------------------+------------+
|    1 |       0 | T CHANDRASHEKAR     | 01/01/2000 |
|    2 |  000102 | A RAMESH            | 01/01/2000 |
|    3 |  601026 | B DEEPAK KUMAR      | 01/01/2000 |
|    4 |  543250 | N VIRUPAKSHAIAH     | 02/01/2000 |
|    5 |  610019 | ANAND S GUNDI       | 15/01/2000 |
|    6 |  535035 | ADAM BASHA          | 27/01/2000 |
|    7 |  625893 | A N MOHAN KUMAR     | 06/02/2000 |
|    8 |  547830 | RAJENDRA NAIK       | 07/02/2000 |
|    9 |  698742 | S M SUSHMA          | 19/02/2000 |
|   10 |  655542 | B JAYACHANDRA       | 24/02/2000 |
|   11 |  624769 | B HANUMANTHAPPA     | 25/02/2000 |
```

It would be better if it is possible using php.  Please help.

Comment: What are you asking? How to get the data from the database or how to output it? If you don't know either then you should probably start by reading a few tutorials.

Comment: `Select * from mytable;`  gives you the above output in command line.  But I want the same format in browser using php code.  Normally, you add html table and format the data, but I want it in ascii text table format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Approach

This is possible. The main difficulty is the variable nature of the string lengths, which will typically cause the output data to be difficult to read.

To address this, I suggest that you:

- Find the maximum string length in each column
- Output Headers with top and lower borders, with header names padded to be same width as maximum cell width
- Output each row with the cells padded to the target column width.

## Code Sample

I'm not able to unit-test the code shown below at present, but it should be ok; post a comment if you have any trouble.

```
<?php

// Open connection
$mysqli = new mysqli("db_host", "db_user", "db_password", "db_schema");

// Check that connection succeeded
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", $mysqli->connect_error);
    exit();
}

// Prepare query
$query = "SELECT * FROM `myTable`";

// Fetch results as associative array
$resultSet = [];
if ($result = $mysqli->query($query)) {

    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $resultSet[] = $row;
    }

    // Free result set
    $result->free();

    // Close Connection to DB
    $mysqli->close();
} else {

  // Close Connection to DB and print error message
  $mysqli->close();
  die('An error occurred when executing SQL, please check your SQL query.');
}



// If results empty, output error
if (count($resultSet)<1) {
  die('<pre>----NO DATA----'+"\n\n"+'Please revise your query</pre>');
}

// Get column names
$keys = array_keys($resultSet[0]);

// Iterate over column names, get starting widths
$maxLength = [];
foreach ($keys as $column) {
  $maxLength[$column] = mb_strlen($column);
}

// Iterate over result-set, get maximum string length for each column
foreach ($resultSet as $row) {
  foreach ($keys as $column) {

    // If current cell length is greater than column width, increase column width
    if (mb_strlen($row[$column]) > $maxLength[$column]) {
      $maxLength[$column] = mb_strlen($row[$column]);
    }

  }
}

echo '<pre>';

// Output top border
echo '+';
foreach ($keys as $column) {
  echo str_repeat('-', $maxLength[$column]+2);
  echo '+';
}
echo "\n";

// Output header
echo '| ';
foreach ($keys as $column) {
  echo $column.str_repeat(' ', $maxLength[$column] - mb_strlen($column));
  echo ' | ';
}
echo "\n";

// Output bottom border
echo '+';
foreach ($keys as $column) {
  echo str_repeat('-', $maxLength[$column]+2);
  echo '+';
}
echo "\n";

// Output all rows
foreach ($resultSet as $row) {
  echo '| ';
  foreach ($keys as $column) {
    echo $row[$column].str_repeat(' ', $maxLength[$column] - mb_strlen($row[$column]));
    echo ' | ';
  }
echo "\n";
}

echo '</pre>';


?>
```

**NOTE**
*The above code is multi-byte safe but it disregards character width; if the output contains characters of variable width then there might be slight 'kinks' in the column separators. This may be worth a revision if you encounter such problems in the display.*

Comment: `+------+---------+---------------------+------------+-------------+| 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | +------+---------+---------------------+------------+-------------+| 

Warning:  main(): Couldn't fetch mysqli_result in C:\xampp\htdocs\bellary\birthdays.php on line 88
` this is what I get

Comment: @adam1969in Corrected typos in the code sample, please re-run and let me know how it goes. I'm on the move so still can't test locally.

Comment: Superb...!  After correcting two more typos in line 71 and 92, it gives out the desired result.  But, the beginning '|' is printed only for two lines and then omitted for all other rows.  Maybe there is some typo somewhere, I will check it soon.  Meanwhile, if you can get it, please convey it.   Excellent once again and thank you very much.

Comment: @adam1969in move the 'echo' statement after the comment 'output all rows' down one line; I.e. Move inside the first for each loop. I've corrected my answer accordingly.

Comment: Perfect @Peter Scott.   Excellent and Hats Off.   Just correct the typos in line 71 ` a ";" after echo "\n" `code` and in line 92 ` echo $row[$column]str_repeat ` a "." is missing, it should be ` $row[$column].str_repeat `.   Everything works perfect.  Thanks a Lot.

Comment: Thank you once again sir

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:** Looks like it's impossible without writing fancy wrapper scripts to emulate the exact MySQL shell output (such as in @PeterScott's answer). The closest you can get to this probably is dumping the output into a temporary file:

```
<?php
mysqli_query("select * from mytable into outfile '/tmp/mytable.out'");
```

and then output this file in a browser, wrapping it in PRE tags:

```
<?php
$output = file_get_contents('/tmp/mytable.out');
echo '<pre>'. $output .'</pre>';
```

No way of grabbing this data directly from MySQL console, I'm afraid.

Comment: Good one, but the horizontal and vertical lines of table are missing, leading into unformatted table data

Comment: @SergeyVidusov See my answer; it seems like some simple string padding makes the output quite easy.

Comment: @PeterScott Exactly what I meant by "fancy wrapper scripts" :)

Comment: @SergeyVidusov Ah, as you were then.

Answer (score 0):

```
mysql -uroot -p dbname -e 'select * from table_name' -H > dump.php
```

then you can visit the table content from browser :http://192.168.2.xx/dump.php

-H in mysql command line means output in HTML format.